# Why freezing hash values before freezing the hash itself?

Tags: ruby, performance

I have noticed that some folks do `{ 'foo': 'bar'.freeze }.freeze` instead of just `{ 'foo': 'bar' }.freeze`.

Is it better? If so, why?

Comment: Ruby strings are mutable by default. So the way first prevents someone from `h[:baz] << "val"` and `h[:foo] << "baz"` whereas the second simply prevents `h[:baz] << "val"` (among other things). "Is it better" is both opinion based and use case dependent, as well as completely ambiguous in the current context (e.g. Is what better? Which way is better?) so I cannot provide a response to this.

Comment: Frozen strings and frozen hashes aren't quite the same thing.

Comment: Further to @engineersmnky's comment, suppose `h = { :a=>'cat' }.freeze`.  Then, `h.object_id #=> 1820` and `h[:a].object_id #=> 1840`. We can't change the hash because it's frozen: `h[:a] = 'dog' #=> FrozenError: can't modify frozen Hash: {:a=>"cat"}`. We can, however, [String#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-replace) `h[:a]` with another string: `h[:a].replace('dog')#=> "dog"`. Note `h #=> {:a=>'dog'}`, `h.object_id #=> 1820` and `h[:a].object_id #=> 1840`...

Comment: ...Now freeze the value of `:a` as well: `h[:a].freeze #=> "dog"`. Then `h[:a].replace('pig') #=> FrozenError: can't modify frozen String: "dog"`.

Answer (score 2):

`hash.freeze` freezes hash itself, but not its values. This means you will no longer be able to assign new values or delete keys, but you can still mutate the existing values:

```
hash = {a: 'hello'}.freeze
hash[:b] = 'there' #=> exception!
hash[:a] = 'hello there' #=> exception!
hash[:a].upcase! #=> no exception
hash #=> {a: 'HELLO'}
```

On the third line we try to assign a new string to an existing key, which fails. But on a fourth line we directly modify the instance of the string. Hash is just keeping references to other objects, so modifying a string does not affect hash at all.

Things are different if you also freeze the string:

```
hash = {a: 'hello'.freeze}.freeze
hash[:a].upcase! #=> exception!
```